# No references on individual pages...?

Tags: bookdown, appearance

I've been using `bookdown` for a while now... but lately I have noticed that the reference list that used to appear at the bottom of each webpage of the product is no longer there.

For example, when I look at one of the chapters in the [bookdown manual](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/latex-index.html), there is a reference list at the bottom of the pages when relevant. So it must still be the way it works; nothing has changed. [But this is not so for any of my `bookdown` documents](https://bookdown.org/pkaldunn/Book/smoking-study.html) (including when I compile the default template "Book Project using bookdown" document in RStudio, so it must not be anything in my documents).

In addition, [my last-chapter Reference list](https://bookdown.org/pkaldunn/Book/references.html) looks [far more squashed and hard to read compared to other bookdown books](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/references.html).

All the references appear OK, and the links work OK. But there must be an issue somewhere. Since it doesn't appear elsewhere, and the the issues appear with the template document too, perhaps it is an issue with my system somehow.

But I have no idea where to start looking. Any idea where to start looking, or how to fix?

Thanks.

P.